# Azure - Python - parse arguments from command line

Tags: python, azure

community,

I am trying to parse arguments as default values for principal credentials on Azure using Python CLI. In my code, I am trying to hardcode the default values for the "**--azure-client-id", "--azure-secret",  "--azure-tenant"** and **"--azure-subscription-id"** as default but I am not 100% how to add it. I have been searching all over the net but can't find the answer as yet

I am still learning and I was hoping that someone could help me.

Thank you in advances for your help

### My code below

`def parse_args(args):
    '''parse arguments from command line'''
    variables = {}
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("action",
                        help="the command to be action",
                        choices=["delete", "create"],
                        nargs='?',
                        default="set")
    parser.add_argument("-f", "--folder",
                        dest="folder",
                        nargs='?',
                        help="folder container ARM template & parameters json",
                        metavar="FOLDER")
    parser.add_argument("-b",
                        "--build-number",
                        dest="build_number",
                        help="build number of the resource number")
    parser.add_argument("-c",
                        "--azure-client-id",
                        dest="azure_client_id",
                        help="azure client id")
    parser.add_argument("-s",
                        "--azure-secret",
                        dest="azure_secret",
                        help="azure secret")
    parser.add_argument("-t",
                        "--azure-tenant",
                        dest="azure_tenant",
                        help="azure tenant")
    parser.add_argument("-sid",
                        "--azure-subscription-id",
                        dest="azure_subscription_id",
                        help="azure subscription id")
    args = parser.parse_args(args)`

Answer (score 0):

> parser.add_argument('--azure-client-id', nargs='?', const='ID',
>   default='ID')

nargs='?' = 0 or 1 arguments

const='ID' = sets default value when no arguments are passed

default='ID' = if '--azure-client-id' is not specified this will be the default value

https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#nargs